# Adding datasets together and continuing the time series in python

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series

I am new to python and wanted to ask if there is a way I could add 2 of 3 data sets together that are read from 2/3 different csv files and continue the time stamp from the previous data set. I am trying to create a time series from multiple csv files which all have the time stamps starting at 0. An added complexity is that the timestamp incrementors are varying for some csv files as described in the example below.

for example if Data set A consists of 2 columns, time and x-coordinate, where time stamps are from 0 to 10 seconds in increments of 0.5s and Data set B consists of the same columns with time ranging from 0-15 seconds in increments of 1 seconds, could I merge the two data sets together so that the time continues from data set A but with the increments of B.

something like this

t, x

9,0.8

9.5,2

10, 0.6

11, 3.3

12,4.4

.

.
25, 2

If this is not really possible would it be easier to do this if the datasets had the same timestamp increments.

Comment: Would the CSVs, be constantly changing (i.e. will it be a stream file) ... else if you are using Pandas, you can read the CSVs' into different dataframes and then concat or merge them together. You can den sort the timestamp field either asc or desc.

Comment: The CSVs wont be a stream file. I have been playing around with pandas and i can merge the data sets together. I dont undertsand what your suggestion for timestamp field is however. Id like the time in my master data base to be continuous, so that if data A time ends at 10s, and the first row in data B is time 1 second, x coord 3.3, after merging the  master data set will read 11,3.3, not 1, 3.3